# Aurelia Jest error - Loader must implement loadTemplate

Tags: jestjs, aurelia, yarnpkg

After updating my `aurelia-dependency-injection` library with Yarn, I started getting the following errors in my Jest tests.

It seems that for some reason the dependency injection library isn't working as expected?

```
  ● Datepicker › click date icon opens calendar

    Loader must implement loadTemplate(url).

      at Loader.loadTemplate (node_modules/aurelia-loader/dist/commonjs/aurelia-loader.js:119:11)
      at ensureRegistryEntry (node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/commonjs/aurelia-templating.js:3382:17)
      at ViewEngine.loadViewFactory (node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/commonjs/aurelia-templating.js:3456:12)
      at RelativeViewStrategy.loadViewFactory (node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/commonjs/aurelia-templating.js:562:23)
      at HtmlBehaviorResource.load (node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/commonjs/aurelia-templating.js:4238:27)
      at ResourceDescription.load (node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/commonjs/aurelia-templating.js:3258:26)
      at ResourceModule.load (node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/commonjs/aurelia-templating.js:3200:23)
      at node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/commonjs/aurelia-templating.js:3587:41
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that my yarn.lock file had duplicate `aurelia-dependency-injection` references:

```
aurelia-dependency-injection@^1.0.0, aurelia-dependency-injection@^1.3.1:
  version "1.4.1"
  resolved "https://private-yarn-mirror/aurelia-dependency-injection/-/aurelia-dependency-injection-1.4.1.tgz#fb916e1809446600fb2cdf062f549060df49ef86"
  dependencies:
    aurelia-metadata "^1.0.0"
    aurelia-pal "^1.0.0"

aurelia-dependency-injection@^1.4.2:
  version "1.4.2"
  resolved "https://private-yarn-mirror/aurelia-dependency-injection/-/aurelia-dependency-injection-1.4.2.tgz#fa9d1a9f4931e353fb8f938ee0c54b9fbf3f341a"
  dependencies:
    aurelia-metadata "^1.0.0"
    aurelia-pal "^1.0.0"
```

My solution was to simply delete the top reference so that my yarn.lock looked like so:

```
aurelia-dependency-injection@^1.4.2:
  version "1.4.2"
  resolved "https://private-yarn-mirror/aurelia-dependency-injection/-/aurelia-dependency-injection-1.4.2.tgz#fa9d1a9f4931e353fb8f938ee0c54b9fbf3f341a"
  dependencies:
    aurelia-metadata "^1.0.0"
    aurelia-pal "^1.0.0"
```

I then executed the following command to ensure the yarn.lock would generate correctly after my manual edit.

- `yarn add aurelia-framework@latest`

After doing so, my yarn.lock looked like this:

```
aurelia-dependency-injection@^1.0.0, aurelia-dependency-injection@^1.3.1, aurelia-dependency-injection@^1.4.1, aurelia-dependency-injection@^1.4.2:
  version "1.4.2"
  resolved "https://private-yarn-mirror/aurelia-dependency-injection/-/aurelia-dependency-injection-1.4.2.tgz#fa9d1a9f4931e353fb8f938ee0c54b9fbf3f341a"
  dependencies:
    aurelia-metadata "^1.0.0"
    aurelia-pal "^1.0.0"
```

Now my Jest tests work fine and everything is working elsewhere as well.

I discovered this article shortly afterwards which discusses the issue, though I personally didn't use the tools there:

- https://medium.com/@scinos/de-duplicating-yarn-lock-ae30be4aa41a